# Kendo datepicker randomly not showing calendar to change date

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-datepicker

I have 2 Kendo UI date pickers on my page to select the start and end date of a date range. On random page loads in these 2 date pickers, one becomes not responding. That is, the calendar is not showing up when clicking on the icon to select a date. This issue mostly happening in chrome.

Comment: Please share your code for this page.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved. This was due to a code issue where controls are binding 2 times. Corrected the code and binding bring down to 1 time and the issue got resolved. So anybody facing a similar issue please validate this scenario too as a step to resolve.

Thank you very much.